# 502 Bad Gateway and failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument using nginx and gunicorn

Tags: nginx, centos7, gunicorn

I already successfully deployed **nginx** and **gunicorn** in my **centos 7** server but got **502 Bad Gateway** error message. I'm using **nginx/1.12.2**. I already check both status for gunicorn and nginx.

gunicorn status

```
● deepagi.service - Gunicorn instance to serve deepagi
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/deepagi.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-12-02 10:49:30 UTC; 41min ago
 Main PID: 1829 (gunicorn)
   CGroup: /system.slice/deepagi.service
           ├─1829 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/python2 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:deepagi.sock -m 007 wsgi
           ├─1834 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/python2 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:deepagi.sock -m 007 wsgi
           ├─1839 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/python2 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:deepagi.sock -m 007 wsgi
           └─1840 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/python2 /root/deepagi/deepagienv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:deepagi.sock -m 007 wsgi

Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve deepagi.
Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI systemd[1]: Starting Gunicorn instance to serve deepagi...
Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI gunicorn[1829]: [2017-12-02 10:49:30 +0000] [1829] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI gunicorn[1829]: [2017-12-02 10:49:30 +0000] [1829] [INFO] Listening at: unix:deepagi.sock (1829)
Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI gunicorn[1829]: [2017-12-02 10:49:30 +0000] [1829] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI gunicorn[1829]: [2017-12-02 10:49:30 +0000] [1834] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1834
Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI gunicorn[1829]: [2017-12-02 10:49:30 +0000] [1839] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1839
Dec 02 10:49:30 DeepAGI gunicorn[1829]: [2017-12-02 10:49:30 +0000] [1840] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1840
```

nginx status

```
● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-12-02 11:16:18 UTC; 14min ago
 Main PID: 2317 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2317 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
           └─2318 nginx: worker process

Dec 02 11:16:18 DeepAGI systemd[1]: Starting The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server...
Dec 02 11:16:18 DeepAGI nginx[2312]: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
Dec 02 11:16:18 DeepAGI nginx[2312]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Dec 02 11:16:18 DeepAGI systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Dec 02 11:16:18 DeepAGI systemd[1]: Started The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server.
```

But I saw in nginx status got this kind of error message

```
Dec 02 11:16:18 DeepAGI systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
```

How to solve this?